# How to show my url json data to collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have get data from one url with authorized header and i convert to `json`.

In my `json` i am having only pdf file. But i don't want to show pdf file. I want to show the file name ( eg : `document1.pdf`, `document2.pdf` ).and also i am having 3 **section** - each contain 10 documents. So i need to show name of the document.

I saw some tutorials which using only image not document file. So how to show my document name alone to collection view.

One more question. does i need to decode to show my data or don't want to do that. Help me out.Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Comment: I need to show my data file (document file) from json responce to collection view

Comment: @user3182143 see my updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    NSMutableArry *arrayPDFName  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSDictionary *dictOriginal = [jsonResultsvalueForKey:@"original"];
    NSArray *arrayFiles = [[dictOriginal valueForKey:@"files"] copy];
    NSLog(@"The arrayFiles are - %@",arrayFiles);
    for(int i=0;i<[arrayFiles count];i++)
    {
        NSString *strCreatedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"created_time"]];
        NSString *strLastModifiedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"last_modified_time"]];
        NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"]];
        NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]];

        NSLog(@"The created_time is - %@",strCreatedTime);
        NSLog(@"The last_modified_time is - %@",strLastModifiedTime);
        NSLog(@"The is is - %@",strID);
        NSLog(@"The name is - %@",strName);

        [arrayPDFName addObject:strName];
    }

}
```

in collectionview you need use the above arrayPDFName(in collection view delegates methods)

Showing data in CollectionView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self getResponse];
  UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
  flowLayout.scrollDirection =  UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
  //Register the custom cell for collection view
  UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
  [collectionViewHorizontalVertical registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
}

//Collection View Delegates method
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
  return  1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return arrayPDFName.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
          //data for text
  cell.textField.text = [arrayPDFName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

           //OR Image

  cell.imgViewCollection.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayPDFName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

  return cell;
}

// If you want to set the cell height
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  return CGSizeMake(200, 200); //Please give your required size
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code..i am new to ios.so not handled collection view so far...can u give your mail id or skype id to help me out

Comment: also only one error i got used unresolve identifier- `jsonResultsvalueForKey`

Comment: Bro i got error in as i mentioned above..`jsonResultsvalueForKey` .please see my post json response. I also need to show the files in other category like draft,deleted,most ---

Comment: In your coding,there is no jsonResultsvalueForKey

Comment: For several section i am having data.see my json in my post.How to so all category data with header