# Not able to print my json data in my console?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

here is my code. I used NSDictionary and coded to print my json data in my console.but i got error like this:

```
   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c971930'
```

My code:

```
  if(buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"OK Button is clicked");
    }
    else if(buttonIndex == 1) {

        if([[textView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length]!=0)
        {
            if(!self.note)
            {
                NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
                NSManagedObject *newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:context];

                NSLog(@"%@",textView.text);

                [newNote setValue:textView.text forKey:@"note"];
                if([textView.text length]>30)
                {
                    [newNote setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",[textView.text substringToIndex:25]] forKey:@"title"];
                }
                else
                    [newNote setValue:textView.text forKey:@"title"];
                [newNote setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"mod_time"];
                //[newDevice setValue:self.versionTextField.text forKey:@"version"];
                //[newDevice setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];
```

How to overcome this problem to work and to print my data in my console
Help me out. I am struggling for 2 hours.I googled and change all change.But cant get data in my console. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you check your response is in correct format in postman or some rest client tool?

Comment: provide NSString *str value here?

Comment: That means any json viewer --sorry i am new to ios.Not heared about these word.if i understand your question menas i just checked the format using Json viewr.

Comment: @ Paresh Navadiya  i too updated my full code

Comment: what line of code throw exception?

Comment: Don't see the "original" key in the log. You should talk with your co-worker.

Comment: @anhtu  yes thats my fault..change that word....see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can get data like below this

```
NSDictionary *monday = jsonResults[@"original"];
NSArray * arrFile = monday[@"files"];
for (NSDictionary *theCourse in arrFile)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Did you update the question? Can you post the result of this line `NSLog(@"str: %@", str);`?

Comment: i cant able to see in json format.and i am getting error `Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSString *'`--                 in my code here:    `  NSArray *monday = strReturnData[@"original"];`

Comment: Sure, you will get this error. Because returnData not a JON. Please post the log of ` NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData 
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSLog(@"str: %@", str);`

Comment: Please see my post. i have doen already this string ,then i convert with JSON to NSDictionary. Till that its working well. I need to display in console only one part of section in my json. For that only i am getting that error----above i post in my question......

Comment: Not mean you have to use my answer. Just want to see what the Log print out. In your code, `NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData 
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSLog(@"str: %@", str);` do nothing.  @Paresh Navadiya is right. Can't help you if you do not post the log of this line `NSLog(@"str: %@", str);`

Comment: i am not able to understand you question. in my console i got many lines of code in unformated JSON type. should i want to post that or some thing other.I am new to ios..sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Please post where you see "str: abc adfdf ...". You should learn more about `NSLog`

Comment: i have posted in my qustion for `NSLog(@"str: %@", str);`

Comment: yes its worked,Thanks a lot.  One more question. if i want to use my data to display in collection view......Should i use `NSDictionary * data = ["key" : "value"]`  to show data in my collection view

Comment: @user5513630 I don't understand your question. :). Anyway, if you want to store anything having `key`, using NSDictionary, if don't need `key`, just use NSArray. For `collectionView` data source, using `NSArray`, each element in array is a `NSDictionary` like `NSDictionary *theCourse and arrFile`

Answer (score 1):

```
// convert Json to NSDictionary
NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

// NSLog(@"%@",jsonResults);
int count = [[jsonResults valueForKey:@"count"] intValue];

NSArray *arrayData = [jsonResults copy];

NSMutableArray *arrayPDFName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i = 0;i < [arrayData count];i++)
{
    NSDictionary *dictOriginal = [[arrayData objectAtIndex:2]valueForKey:@"original"];
    int countOriginal = [[dictOriginal valueForKey:@"count"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"The countOriginal is - %d",countOriginal);
    NSArray *arrayFiles = [[dictOriginal valueForKey:@"files"] copy];
    NSLog(@"The arrayFiles are - %@",arrayFiles);
    for(int j=0;j<[arrayFiles count];j++)
    {
        NSString *strCreatedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"created_time"]];
        NSString *strLastModifiedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"last_modified_time"]];
        NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"id"]];
        NSString *strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayFiles objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"name"]];

        NSLog(@"The created_time is - %@",strCreatedTime);
        NSLog(@"The last_modified_time is - %@",strLastModifiedTime);
        NSLog(@"The is is - %@",strID);
        NSLog(@"The name is - %@",strName);

        [arrayPDFName addObject:strName];
    }

}
```

Comment: `NSArray *monday = jsonResults[@"original"];
        
        for (id item in jsonResults)
        {
            [monday addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item[@"Original"]]];
        }` i have changed but got error------`No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'`

Comment: Change the array to NSMutableArray then only you can add the object

Comment: same error getting-------`
    NSMutableArray *monday = jsonResults[@"original"];
    for (id item in jsonResults) {
        [monday addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item[@"Original"]]];
         NSLog(@"%@",monday);`

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79ef2540'`

Comment: Do you get response first?

Comment: Ok don't worry.I updated my answer please go through.It works fine.

Comment: Your code  get me error....This is that error----`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a0c8a00'`

Comment: Now I updated my code.Please let me know it's working or not?

Comment: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7860c700'`---got error

Comment: `NSDictionary *dictOriginal = [[arrayData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"original"];`

Comment: Thank finally i got it.Now It definitely works hope:-)

Comment: again error `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x799ef400'`  in my code line ---`int countOriginal = [[dictOriginal valueForKey:@"count"] intValue];`

Comment: not able to run...error exception thread occur in same line i mentioned above

Comment: very exactly in which line?

Comment: Tell me the difference between above ticked answer and my answer

Comment: That answer is worked to print the particular data in console ..I too tried with your code i got error

Comment: I answered you get all values from original dictionary from above my coding.

Comment: Put break point in which line are you getting error.Show me that.

Comment: yes i tried your code too.it din run.I got error only. If So please solve my problem here i have asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471932/how-to-show-my-url-json-data-to-colletion-view

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked that received data (i.e., returnData) from sendSynchronousRequest: is returning a plain data?

If the data received is in Base64, you might have to decode this NSData to plain data, and then go ahead with String conversion.

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedData:responseData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: does it important to decode data and to display in collection view.Because i need to display my data in collection view. should i  need to deode it ??